# What is the operator form of 1/Px?

Tags: math, physics

I know that the operator form of 1/Px (Px is the x component of momentum operator P) should have an integral form like:  i/hbar*int(dx), but I'm not sure about the limits of integral. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I should ask this in Physics.stackexchange let me know to delete it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [physics.se] or [math.se] instead of programming.

Answer (score 1):

The limits should be from minus infinity to plus infinity.  The follows from the expectation value of x.  There is a nice answer on [Physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77457/what-is-the-momentum-operator)

I don't have a high enough reputation to leave this in as a comment so I hope you forgive me.

Comment: Thanks I asked this in [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89094/what-is-the-operator-form-of-1-p-x). I asked from my proffesor, he also said that the interval shoulb be symetric. but yet there is one stiky point in p=0.